# SQLite Join command issue Unity

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sqlite, unity-game-engine

i'm using sqlite database in my Unity project and i need to create a new table using Join statement, like this

```
string
        sql = "create table ResultTable2 as select name_journal from Journal INNER JOIN  Points.name_point ON Points.id_journal = Journal.id_journal";
        command = new SqliteCommand(sql, ActiveConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And I have an exception: "cannot find table Points.name_point"

So how can I do this? I learned that for this you can use linq to sql but I'm not sure if it works in Unity.
Ultimately i need to convert this table to XML file..

I tried this:

```
            var w = "select j.name_journal, p.name_point,w.name_workplace, w.percent_workplace from Journal j INNER JOIN Points p ON p.id_journal = j.id_journal INNER JOIN Workplace w ON w.id_point = p.id_point";

        var ds = new DataSet();
        using (var da = new SqliteDataAdapter(q, sqc))
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        ds.WriteXml(@"d:\data.xml");
```

but the xml file was empty.
maybe I didn’t make the request correctly..
Or is it impossible to do in Unity and I need to use Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

You can't join a column, only a table. You have to select the column from the joined table. Given your second query I feel like you already knew this but just made a mistake. I'd also recommend using a StringBuilder object to build your queries.

```
StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

sqlBuilder.AppendLine("CREATE TABLE ResultTable2 AS"); 
sqlBuilder.AppendLine("    SELECT Journal.name_journal, Points.name_point"); 
sqlBuilder.AppendLine("    FROM Journal"); 
sqlBuilder.AppendLine("    INNER JOIN Points ON Points.id_journal = Journal.id_journal");


command = new SqliteCommand(sqlBuilder.ToString(), ActiveConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: SqliteException: SQLite error
near "(": syntax error

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: SqliteException: SQLite error
near "INNER": syntax error

Comment: Are you using StringBuilder like I said? Show me your actual query string.

Comment: Edited my post to use StringBuilder and show how to use it with C#.

Comment: Got a new exception ..
SqliteException: SQLite error
no such column: Points.name_points

It seems to me that he does not understand that he is referring to the table.

Comment: That was a typo on my part, my apologies. Change the query to say "Points.name_point" instead of "Points.name_points". Fixed the example to reflect the changes.

Comment: Happy to help. Be sure to mark the question as answered in case anyone else has the problem they will know where to look :)